# Undefined property: Illuminate\Notifications\Anonymous Notifiable::$name

Tags: laravel, notifications

Trying to use On-demand notification in Laravel 5.8 and ran into this error. I followed the tutorials and it worked fine for them but I ran into this error.

Comment: your question is not clear. please give the code or sample actually what do yo did and what error comes?

Comment: Notification::route('mail', 'blackorange1905@gmail.com')->notify(new OrderNotification($order_data));
This is the triggering code and the title of this post is the error I am facing.

Comment: Could you share the code for **OrderNotification**. might be a problem in there.

Comment: I found and solved the issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @NirojMaharjan Kindly share the solution here. Thanks.